# Saving an ArrayList in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist

I want to switch to MongoDB for my database system. I have a Player class and I basically want to save that to the database. In the player class is a name, rank and a list of purchased items. What is the best way to store all this in MongoDB? I can create a document for the player but are you able to store a list in there? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can store arrays into mongodb 
first create a player document like this

```
db.player.insert({name:"xxx",rank:1});
```

you can insert the empty list at the time of creation like below or it will dynamically create when you update the document.

```
 db.player.insert({name:"xxx",rank:1,purchases:[]});//empty array optional
```

after creating the document you can update document with array like this

```
db.player.update({name:"xxx"},{$push:{purchases:["t-shirt","shoes"]});
```

It will create  document like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1234,
  “name": “xxxx”,
  "rank": 1,
  “purchases”:
  [
           "t-shirt",
           "shoes"  
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can store list, look at [MongoDB embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use and store Arrays in MongoDB.

Check out this article. It will help you a lot: http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/